# Can't see column permissions in properties SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, security, permissions

everyone! I'm trying to grant column-level permissions in SQL Server Management Studio, however, when I click on "Properties" option, the permissions option is not available.
The table level permissions work fine.

Comment: [Working for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ9DO.png) - what version of SQL Server (`SELECT @@VERSION;`) and what version of SSMS (Help > About)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had this question also.  Basically, you can see permissions for an entire table by going to the Properties of the table and then to the Permissions page.  However, if you go to the Properties of a column, there isn't a Permissions page; so how do you view in SSMS what the permissions are for a column? I found the answer in this article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/  Basically, you go the table's Properties, then to the Permissions page and if a particular user has a permission on only some columns and not the whole table, then instead of a checkmark in the Grant box, there will be a square. Click on that line and the *Column Permissions* button is activated - look around for it.  Click on that button and you can see which columns have been granted that right and also set column permissions there. It's not straightforward or intuitive, so this is a very good question.